# customize search result web part

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, search-results

I'm working with SharePoint Foundation 2013 and use SharePoint Designer 2013.
My goal is to get a list from all tasks across a websitecollection for the logged in user.

I try to use the search result web part because it is available for the foundation version. This works but I want to add some columns or fields and change the layout.
Display template is not supported for foundation and for JS Link there is no link in this weep part properties. I even wanted to use xslt but did not find a documentation. I'm very frustrated because I'm always running into dead end streets because in one case the web part is not for foundation in the other case the features like display templates or JS Link are not supported.
Can anybody show me the right way? Every tip is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it, but I have heard that Display Templates are supported in Foundation. You just need to get them from server and drop them into the Master Page Catalog. It's worth a try.